# tvOS: Detecting the orientation of the remote control

Tags: xcode, swift, tvos, tvos9.1

I need to detect when the remote control has change orientation from landscape to portrait and vice versa.

Any of you knows how can this be implemented?

Comment: Have you looked at: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18861?

Comment: @squarehippo10 in the link above is talking about GCMicroGamepad and my question is regarding the appleTV remote control

Comment: theGCMicroGamepad is what you use to access the Apple TV remote.  You can find some basic setup info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832541/how-to-get-motion-events-with-the-apple-tv-remote